# How get result in own remplate Typeahead UI Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I use Angular JS library `Typeahead UI` from Bootstrap.
I try to load data from server by AJAX request.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="result" typeahead-template-url="/public/html/education_autocomplete.html" typeahead="suggestion for suggestion in getEducation($viewValue)">
```

Angular JS:

```
    $scope.getEducation = function (education){
         return $http.jsonp("/other/GetEducation/"+education).then(function(response){
         return response;
     });
  }
```

Response from server is:

```
[{"IdEducation":"6","NameEducation":"\u0421\u0440\u0435\u0434\u043d\u044f\u044f \u0448\u043a\u043e\u043b\u0430 19","idUser":"570"},{"IdEducation":"7","NameEducation":"\u0421\u0417\u0413\u041c\u0423 \u0418.\u0418.\u041c\u0435\u0447\u043d\u0438\u043a\u043e\u0432\u0430","idUser":"585"},{"IdEducation":"5","NameEducation":"Kharkiv National Medical University","idUser":"570"},{"IdEducation":"8","NameEducation":"Az\u0259rbaycan D\u00f6vl\u0259t Tibb Universiteti","idUser":"588"}]
```

How to show data from response in own template HTML?
Now I get nothing. I think problem is in:

`suggestion for suggestion in`

Also I tried:

```
typeahead="state as state.NameEducation for state in getEducation($viewValue)"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use custom template like this.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="customSelected" placeholder="Custom template" typeahead="edu as edu.NameEducation for edu in educations | filter:{NameEducation:$viewValue}" typeahead-template-url="customEduTemplate.html" class="form-control">
```

Here is a [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/JQLwJfRbsaENZQ8cy23c?p=preview) . For more details you can always refer to [angular-bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

Comment: I have done following this example. but for me does not work, I get data from server, but it does not show in HTML

Comment: See my question please, your answer from tutorial

Comment: For me does not work: `typeahead="edu as edu.NameEducation for edu in getEducation($viewValue)"` where `getEducation` function was described in question

Comment: Oh i haven't seen  your `getEducation()` function ,here you go  http://plnkr.co/edit/JQLwJfRbsaENZQ8cy23c?p=preview

Comment: My function `getEducation()` : `$scope.getEducation = function (education){
                    return $http.jsonp("/other/GetEducation/"+education).then(function(response){
                        return response
                    });

                }`

Comment: I cannot make  call to external service because I don't have backend service up and running, you need to change the code inside `getEducation` to call your service.

Comment: Seems I know what is problem, when I remove AJAX and set here simply string - it works. Maybe problem in return in AJAX?

Comment: Could be, please check what is the call made to backend

Comment: Thanks for all. Problem was in `return response.data;` instead `return response;` (:

Comment: Please consider posting a new question describing the exact problem.